# How to handle umlaute in data.table character keys?

Tags: r, key, data.table

Is there a way to handle Umlaute in data.tables keys? 
At the moment data.table returns the following order with Äxempel at the bottom, when, in my case, it should be at the top of the list.

```
dat <- data.table(names = c("peter", "björn", "john", "äxempel"), num = 1:4)
setkey(dat, names)
dat

     names num
1:   björn   2
2:    john   3
3:   peter   1
4: äxempel   4
```

Comment: Why does it matter how it is "keyed" in data.table? `sort(c("peter", "björn", "john", "äxempel"))` sorts as expected.

Comment: You could make a new column with modified names. Modification can be done with ``gsub("ä", "ae", names)``, ... . You sort by the new names then.

Comment: You can use `dat[base::order(names)]` as a workaround if you just want to sort, and keep in mind that you don't need to `setkey` anymore - using `on` will work just fine no matter the sort locale.

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about the gsub workaround myself, but the base::order function works just as fine. It would be nice though if data.table behaved as expected as well .